# No route found for "GET /user" on Symfony 5 in docker container

Tags: php, docker, symfony, php-8

To create a web-service, I create a new project with a container *php-nginx* for web-server, *postgresql-13* for db, so I create my Dockerfile based on `FROM php:7.4-fpm-alpine` for php-nging container and docker-compose.yml for my developments.
Previously to run container, I create symfony squeleton in my local (host under Ubuntu Bionic) folder and run `make:entity user`  and `make:crud User` to have basic views.

After run containers, I try to open url localhost:8000/user and it returns :
`No route found for "GET /user"`

I check on my local (host) with `php bin/console debug:router`, it returns :

```
…
user_index                 GET        ANY      ANY    /user/                             
user_new                   GET|POST   ANY      ANY    /user/new                          
user_show                  GET        ANY      ANY    /user/{id}
```

routes seems ok
but if I do the same in the container, no route for user.

The question is why routes is OK in host and not in the docker container ?

Comment: Please share more details and your debugging attempts

Comment: @Nico, Thanks for your interest, I can add my Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml but I don't see in what way it helps people who have the same issue? and regarding debug the debug:router in host and in container is the key, Others tests, for example regarding files or folder owner in container doesn't help to understand the issue

Comment: More details are pretty welcome, just to ensure that this helps other with the same issue. Without providing any attempts to resolve the problem (like: Dockerfiles, PHP configuration, Symfony configuration), it's pretty likely that nobody can provide help, and thus nobody can learn from your situation

Comment: @NicoHaase I agree with you if I didn't find how to solve this issue, but as it is solved, I think it is enough to help people how have this error with Sf5 in docker, no?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So I connect to the container `docker exec -it my-web-container sh`,
then test to create a new entity… `php bin/console make:entity test` and look routes in *src/Controller*

Annotations are different :

```
/**
 * @Route("/test")
 */
class TestController extends AbstractController
```

and for user :

```
#[Route('/user')]
class UserController extends AbstractController
```

and the reason is that even if I use Ubuntu bionic with default PHP 7.2, I recently update to PHP 7.4 (using ppa:ondrej/php) support… and it update to PHP-8 ! and when I make:entity from the host, it use new PHP 8 annotation instead of Doctrine annotation, look at https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-5-2-php-8-attributes for more details.

### Solution 1 : switch my container to PHP 8

update my container by change to `FROM php:8-fpm-alpine`

### Solution 2 : stay with Doctrine annotations

but it require to make:entity inside the container… or do write it manually… but perhaps there are a config to define we want to stay to doctrine annotations?